# Case Statement if all NULL or at least one value present

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I could be doing this wrong, but here's as much detail on where I'm at with my thinking.

I have a table, which we'll call table:

```
Test     ID     Value
test_1   01     50
test_2   01     NULL
test_3   01     40/50
test_1   02     NULL
test_2   02     NULL
```

**Summary**

I am just looking to make a CASE expression where I can if all the test values are NULL then 'No' if at least one test value has a value then 'Yes'.

**Desired Output:**

```
ID   Case
01   Yes
02   No
```

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT
    ID
   ,CASE WHEN t.test IN ('test_1','test_2','test_3') IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'  END
FROM table t
```

**Error**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

Comment: @scsimon thanks. Where can I use one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an aggregate....

```
declare @table table (test varchar(6), id int, value varchar(24))
insert into @table
values
('test_1','01','50'),
('test_2','01',NULL),
('test_3','01','40/50'),
('test_1','02',NULL),
('test_2','02',NULL)

select
    t.id
    ,case when min(t.value) is null and max(t.value) is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end as [Case]
from
    @table t
group by
    t.id
```

And really, you only need to check it once.

```
select
    t.id
    ,case when max(t.value) is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end as [Case]
from
    @table t
group by
    t.id
```

Comment: Would this actually insert new data into the table, as I only have read-only access?

Comment: No. Just replace the @table with your table name. I just created some test data to show you how it works... as you can see there is no `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements....

Comment: Ok, just wondered because I saw Insert under Declare. I'm not used to queries with statements before SELECT

Comment: that's because i created a table variable to store the test data. Just google table variable or tempt table and read about it